# Speeding up triple loop

Tags: python, numpy, time, reduction

Initially I had the loop

```
import numpy

datos = numpy.random.rand(1000,17)
clusters = 250
n_variables = 17
centros = numpy.random.rand(clusters,n_variables)
desviaciones = numpy.random.rand(n_variables)
W=1
H=numpy.zeros((len(datos), clusters))
Weight = 1 / n_variables
for k in range(len(datos)):
    inpt = datos[k]
    for i in range(clusters):
        for j in range(n_variables):
            sup = centros[i][j] + W * desviaciones[j]
            inf = centros[i][j] - W * desviaciones[j]
            feat = np.array(inpt[j])
            if (feat < sup and feat > inf):
                H[k, i] += Weight
```

but a triple loop can slow the process a lot. Then, I could reduce it to:

```
import numpy

datos = numpy.random.rand(1000,17)
clusters = 250
n_variables = 17
centros = numpy.random.rand(clusters,n_variables)
desviaciones = numpy.random.rand(n_variables)
W=1
H=numpy.zeros((len(datos), clusters))
sup = centros + W*desviaciones
inf = centros - W*desviaciones
Weight = 1 / n_variables
for k in range(len(datos)):
    inpt = datos[k]
    for i in range(clusters):
        suma = (sup[i]>inpt)&(inf[i]<inpt)
        H[k,i]=suma.sum()*Weight
```

so I could save a loop, but I have problems trying to reduce the others loop using numpy functions. The only left is to repeat the formula of 'suma' for each row of sup and  datos. Do you know any way of doing it?

Comment: Could you make this example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Okay, I have defined the arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape `centros` and `datos` to three dimensions to take advantage of broadcasting:

```
centros = centros[None, :, :]    # (   1, 250, 17)  
datos = datos[:, None, :]        # (1000,   1, 17)
desv = W * desviaciones
sup = centros + desv
inf = centros - desv
H = Weight * ((datos < sup) & (datos > inf)).sum(axis=2)
```